# removeEventListener after button click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a first button where I add an event listener to execute foo function.
The foo function just displays a number in console.

I have a second button for removing the event listener added.

Here the code, very simple:

```
<input type="button" value="Click here" id="button">

<input type="button" value="Remove Event Listener" onclick="removeEventListener();">

<script type="text/javascript">

number = 0;

//Function to display number in console :
function foo()
{
    number = number+1;
    
    console.log(number);    
}

//The button :
button = document.getElementById("button");

//Add event listener to the button :
button.addEventListener("click", foo);

//Function to remove event listener :
function removeEventListener()
{
    button.removeEventListener("click", foo);   
}

</script>
```

You can try it : https://jsfiddle.net/6m8z8qgn/

But when I click in the second button to remove the event listener,
the event listener added to the first button is not removed, so console displays number again when I click in the first button.

An idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the name of the method removeEventListener to something else. Otherwise it is referred to javascript internal method.

function renameThis()

Comment: Thank you very much ! Solved.

Answer (score 1):

`removeEventListener` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript.

Try something else.

```
<input type="button" value="Remove Event Listener" onclick="anotherName();">
<input type="button" value="Click here" id="button">
<script type="text/javascript">

number = 0;

//Function to display number in console :
function foo()
{
number = number+1;

console.log(number);    
}

//The button :
button = document.getElementById("button");

//Add event listener to the button :
button.addEventListener("click", foo);

//Function to remove event listener :
function anotherName()
{
    button.removeEventListener("click", foo);   
}
```